# Why is not gm's method 'toBuffer' promisified?

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, gm

I tried to use [gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) to resize a big avatar image to 64 * 64.
The express function is an async function and I tried to promisify all methods  by the following codes:

```js
import gm_origin from 'gm'
import Promise from 'bluebird';
const gm = Promise.promisifyAll(gm_origin);

...
const processThumb = async (req, res) => {
  
  const thumbFile = gm(req.file.buffer).resize(config.thumbSize);
  const thumbBuffer = await thumbFile.toBufferAsync('JPG');
  ...
}
```

But the API does not respond at all.
So I set a breakpoint to the line and it is saying that thumbFile does not have 'goBufferAsync' method.
Is anybody know how to promisify all methods of 'gm'?

Comment: Apparently the prototoype of `thumbFile` is not accessible from `gm`, so it cannot promisify it. Use `Promise.promisifyAll(thumbFile)` instead.

Comment: If there was an error like that, it should not "not respond at all", but rather call your error handler. You have one, right?

Comment: Could you tell me how to promisify all methods of gm ? Or it doesn't support  'promise'?

Comment: `toBuffer` appears not to be a `gm` method, it's a `thumbFile` method.

Comment: Have you ever seen https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/320 ?

Comment: So have you tried `Promise.promisifyAll(gm_origin.prototype);` as it was used in the Bluebird issue referenced from there?

Comment: I have also tried it but it was same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122005/discussion-between-colin-witkamp-and-bergi).